# Set CodeLite Resources with Premake

Tags: resources, codelite, premake

Is there a possible way to configure Resources Compiler Options (https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUgCS.png) in CodeLite with premake4.lua file?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible right now. You can [submit an issue](https://bitbucket.org/premake/premake-dev/issues); attaching a sample project script would help get it done. Or a pull request would be even better.